# Limit of a sequence when N does not depend on epsilon.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $S_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. If there is some $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ it is true that$$|S_n-L|<\varepsilon,$$
where $N$ DOES NOT depend on $\varepsilon$, then it is true that all but a finite number of terms of $S_n$ are equal to $L$.

Any idea how to prove this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_n \neq L$ with $n >N$. Take $\epsilon =|S_n-L|$ to get a contradiction.